# How to Block Shipment Custom Methods on Custom Add To Cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have use [Conditional Shipping and Payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/)
commercial plugin.
It actually set a unique shipping method, based on the shipping class assigned to a product (or a variation).

I have a custom add to cart on product pages.

If I update something from cart page, then it works perfectly and set a unique shipping method as required.
Is there set a unique shipping method using my custom add to cart code?

**When I have added product from Product Page:**
[image]

**When I have updated product from Cart Page:**
[image]

**JS Code for**

```js
product_data.push({
    product_id: product_id,
    quantity: quantity,
    checkbox_field: m2_checkbox_field,
    m2_quantity_field: m2_quantity,
    m2_price_field: m2_price,
    agree_special_product_field: agree_special_product,
    m2_available_stock: m2_available_stock,
    product_m2_per_peice_value: product_m2_per_peice_value,
    m2_pack_condition: m2_pack_condition,
});
```

**PHP Add To Cart Code**

```
$shipping_classes = ['express-shipping']; // Array of shipping class slugs
$cart_item_data['shipping_classes'] = $shipping_classes;

$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data);
```

Comment: The poor provided code doesn't allow anyone to reproduce the issue that you are facing.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec if want to reproduce the issue then you need to bought the plugin. I was just telling the scenario and searching what need to be fixed

Comment: Actually, nobody can guess that by magic, sorry.